# preg match for xml output node

Tags: php, preg-match

I have the following script that uses the api on *hostip.info*. The page parses an xml readout of a user location based on the ip address. In my function everything is working except for the city.

```
preg_match("@<Hostip>(\s)*<gml:name>(.*?)</gml:name>@si",$xml,$city_match);
```

I have narrowed it down to my `preg_match` being wrong but I'm not sure how to fix it. Here is a sample xml output: http://api.hostip.info/?ip=12.215.42.19

```
<?php
function getCountryCity()
{
    if(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) && strlen($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) > 0)  {
        $ipAddr = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        // verify the IP address
        ip2long($ipAddr)== -1 || ip2long($ipAddr) === false ? trigger_error("Invalid IP", E_USER_ERROR) : "";

        $ipDetail=array();
        // get the XML result from hostip.info
        $xml = file_get_contents("http://api.hostip.info/?ip=".$ipAddr);

        // get the city name inside the node <gml:name> and </gml:name>
        preg_match("@<Hostip>(\s)*<gml:name>(.*?)</gml:name>@si",$xml,$city_match);
        $ipDetail['city'] = $city_match[1]; 

        // get the country name inside the node <countryName> and </countryName>
        preg_match("@<countryName>(.*?)</countryName>@si",$xml,$country_match);
        $ipDetail['country'] = $country_match[1];

        // get the country name inside the node <countryName> and </countryName>
        preg_match("@<countryAbbrev>(.*?)</countryAbbrev>@si",$xml,$cc_match);
        $ipDetail['country_code'] = $cc_match[1];

        // return the array containing city, country and country code
        return $ipDetail;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

$ipDetail = getCountryCity();
$user_city = $ipDetail['city'];
$user_country = $ipDetail['country'];
$user_cc = $ipDetail['country_code'];

echo $user_country.' ('.$user_cc.')';
echo $user_city;

?>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot use an XML parser for this?

Comment: this would be literally the only thing i need an xml parser for, not sure if its worth installing if this stupid preg replace is easily fixable

Comment: What PHP version are you running?

Comment: im running 5.4.5 locally but 5.2.17 online

Comment: You can (and should IMHO) use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) which is in PHP by default as of 5. because regex is not suitable to parse HTML. Even if it doesn't bite you in the ass right now it will in the future.

Comment: thanks yea i searched stack and found something like what u just described and its working fine. thanks!

Comment: with DOMDocument here's an xpath example:
http://jp.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php#87645

your xpath to get the value would look like: '//gml:name/text()' for example

Comment: @Alex Good call to go that route! You're welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getCountryCity() {
    if(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) && strlen($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) > 0)  {
        $user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $response = file_get_contents('http://api.hostip.info/?ip='.$user_ip);
        $user_details = array();
        $xml = new DOMDocument();
        $xml->loadXml($response);
        $xpath = new DOMXpath($xml);
        $path = '/HostipLookupResultSet/gml:featureMember/Hostip/';

        // create values for array
        $ip = $xpath->evaluate($path . 'ip')->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $city = $xpath->evaluate($path . 'gml:name')->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $countryName = $xpath->evaluate($path . 'countryName')->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $countryAbbrev = $xpath->evaluate($path . 'countryAbbrev')->item(0)->nodeValue;

        // assign values to array
        $user_details['ip'] = $ip;
        $user_details['city'] = $city;
        $user_details['countryName'] = $countryName;
        $user_details['countryAbbrev'] = $countryAbbrev;

        return $user_details;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

XPATH is a dream for this kind of stuff. Google "SimpleXML PHP Tutorial" if this is new to you. Basically:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($yourXML);
$user_city = $xml->xpath('//gml:name/text()');
$user_country= $xml->xpath('//countryName/text()');
$cc= $xml->xpath('//countryAbbrev/text()');
```

I find XPATH queries to be much easier to write than RegEx.

Sorry this doesn't answer your question as directly as you want. tried to post in a comment but the formatting gets totally screwed up

Comment: thanks man i voted yours up but i made a more rubust solution that i can use

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match_all("@<gml:name>(.*?)</gml:name>@si",$xml,$city_match);
```

just remove `<Hostip>(\s)*` and use preg_match_all it will take all the tags. Then you can select one you need in array.